# Is using admin database in MongoDB a bad practice if I use only one database inside and one user in general?

Tags: mongodb

Just as in the title.
Is there any point of caring about what database I put my data to if I don't plan anywhere in the future to use more than one user and more than one database?

Will it be a problem if I put my application data into `admin` db in the future? I can restore my backups and they work.

If I use this potentially bad practice, how to change it? Just copy the admin collection onto the other one and that's it?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: It has enough details to be answered.

Comment: Same answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76106029/is-using-admin-database-in-mongodb-a-bad-practice-if-i-use-only-one-database-ins/76107630#76107630 and yes, you can simply copy the collections. You may have to adapt the privileges, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48253839/what-is-the-admin-database-in-mongodb/67159335#67159335